# PHP-Blind SQL injection in "x-forwarded-for" header

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Today i checked my script with acunetix and found a "Blind SQL injection" in one of my files.

**Accunetix Message:**

> Attack details
>
> HTTP Header input x-forwarded-for was set to 1' and sleep(2)='
>
> How to fix this vulnerability:
>
> Your script should filter metacharacters from user input.
> Check detailed information for more information about fixing this vulnerability.

I have escaped all input with mysql_real_escape_string() func, but error existing yet.

I tried to filter this header in my file with this code:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes(($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])));
```

But doesn't work. please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to use a PDO prepared statement to prevent SQL injection, than to try to create your own "scripts" and just escaping characters is not enough to prevent SQL injections

Have a look here for PDO prepared statement : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your application utilizes some sort of **flawed** function "to determine visitor's IP address."

Taking aside the fact that using `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` for this purpose is **wrong**, most likely it explains why your awkward escaping doesn't work.

It seems that the system takes an IP address in some variable *before* you escape it. And then this variable goes into query, while you are escaping harmless XFF.

And here goes the **real** explanation, why you ought to use prepared statements: **because they format the exactly proper value, right where it should be.** Makes it no way to slip up with too early escaping.